# [op amp - Gain current source - current reference]

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, current-source, gain, reference

I have a question about the formula to consider for calculation of the gain for the electronic bellow.
[image]

Thanks for your support.

Comment: To formulate a gain relationship you need to show where the input signal is and where the output signal is.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks for your reply. If I consider that my V input is the voltage across R1 and V output is the voltage across R3. Can I say that the gain is equal to  R3/R1 ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that - you need to show a voltage source as the input. There needs to be cause and effect.

Comment: @Andyaka: So If I understand your explanation for my circuit schematic there is no real gain formula to use ? Are you agree with my point ? Thanks

Comment: That's how I see it.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks. One more question about this circuit. If I consider that I have a variable resistor instead of R3, is there any formula to determine the curent flowing through the variable resistor/or a formula to determine the voltage across the variable resistor ? Thanks

Comment: The current through R3 is 6.2 volts / 22 kohm or V(D1)/R2 as I explained in my answer on the previous question.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks for your answer. So If I get your point, regardless the value of the power supply (in my case 25.2): the R3 current will always be equal to V(D1)/R2 ? Are you agree with me ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the power supply gets too low then the op-amp will stop working. If it gets too big the op-amp will burn so, not regardless of the power supply.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks for your support. However, when I used the simulation circuit [link](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=55g2e3f2753f). If I use the formula 6.2(VD)/22K then multiplying the value obtained by 5K (R3) I don't get 19.5V as the simulator circuit result. Is there anything wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: We're drifting away from your question so I'm going to stop moving down this snaking ever-changing path. This is a Q and A site - you ask formal questions and we supply answers. We help a bit with this and that but now is time to draw the line. Your question is unanswerable because you can't propose an input source. I did your "one more question" several comment ago.

Comment: @Andyaka: Thanks for all your explanation. I get your idea with all my respect. I will close the question. Best regards.

Comment: Fixing the question would be better than closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real gain formula to use for my circuit because there is no input voltage source showed. I thank you for all feedback and explanation about my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the voltage across R3 to be equal to that across R1, switch the inputs and move the feedback to the collector of Q1.  Right now it's ensuring that the voltage across R2 is the same as the voltage across D1.  Still a constant current arrangement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I get your point my circuit will be a voltage reference if I apply the changement that you suggest ?

Comment: The op amp in this configuration is controlling a voltage.  The voltage it controls is the one at the point where the feedback is coming from.  This circuit as shown puts out a constant voltage 25.2-V(D1) at the emitter, and pulls as much current through R2 as needed to set that voltage.  The current will be constant as well, as the voltage on the other side of R2 is fixed.  The same (fixed) current will go through R3 (minus the base current), so the voltage across R3 will also be constant at 5/22 * V(R2).  Where is the load you want to feed current to?